# How to get this hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cavity-qed

I'm trying to follow the paper (https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.78.3221) where cavity qed is used for quantum network.

In this paper, they made a hamiltonian like

\begin{equation}
\hat H_1 = w_c \hat a^†_1\hat a_1 + w_0|r\rangle_{11}\langle r| + g(|r\rangle_{11}\langle g|\hat a_1 + H.c.) + \frac{1}{2}Ω_1(t)[e^{-i[w_Lt+φ_1(t)]}|r\rangle_{11}\langle e| + H.c.] \end{equation}

where $ħ=1$.

Here, $\hat a_1$ is the desctruction operator for cavity mode i with frequency $w_c$, $|g\rangle_1, |r\rangle_1$ and $|e\rangle_1$ form a three-level system of excitation frequency $w_0$ as you can see on the figure below.

[image]

The ground state $|g\rangle_1$ and $|e\rangle_1$ are degenerate, and these two states are coupled by a Raman transition, where a laser of frequency $w_L$ excites the atom from $|e\rangle_1$ to $|r\rangle_1$ with a time-dependent Rabi frequency $Ω_1(t)$, followed by a transition $|r\rangle_1$ to $|g\rangle_1$ which is accompanied by emission of a photon into the corresponding cavity mode, with coupling constant $g$.

In this paper, they tried to avoid spontaneous emission from the excited state during the Raman process by strongly detuning the laser frequency from the atomic transition $|\Delta|\ggΩ_1(t),g,|φ_1|$ (with $\Delta=w_l-w_0$). They say, in this case, one can eliminate adiabatically the excited states $|r\rangle_1$, and the new Hamiltonian for the dynamics of the two ground state becomes, in a rotating frame for the cavity modes at the laser frequency,

$$ \hat H_1 = -δ \hat a^†_1\hat a_1 + \frac{g^2}{\Delta}\hat a_1^†\hat a_1|g\rangle_{11}\langle g| + \frac{Ω_1(t)^2}{4\Delta}|e\rangle_{11}\langle e|-i\frac{g Ω_1(t)}{2\Delta}[e^{iφ_1(t)}|e\rangle_{11}\langle g|\hat a_1-H.c] $$

where $δ = w_L-w_c$.

I tried to transform it back to the stationary frame like

$$ \hat H_1 = w_c \hat a^†_1\hat a_1 + \frac{g^2}{\Delta}\hat a^†_1\hat a_1|g\rangle_{11}\langle g| + \frac{Ω_1(t)^2}{4\Delta}|e\rangle_{11}\langle e|-i\frac{g Ω_1(t)}{2\Delta}[e^{i[w_Lt+φ_1(t)]}|e\rangle_{11}\langle g|\hat a_1-H.c] $$

My question is how to get the last equation from the first one.

I could see that the last equation has been obtained by multiplying the interaction Hamiltonians or squaring itself in the first equation with throwing away the term, $w_0|r\rangle_{11}\langle r|$.

I want to know how the procedure to get the last Hamiltonian was from the first Hamiltonian.

Comment: I think that they follow the process outlines here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1090.pdf hope it helps